# jQuery Mobile : calling JavaScript function

Tags: jquery-mobile

How can I call a JavaScript function while using jQuery Mobile?

Comment: I don't understand. Just call it?

Comment: What problems are you having?

Comment: Sorry guys...Found the answer ..You have add "rel='external'" in every link in your project when using jquery mobile only than the new page will behave like normal page :)...If you think I was stupid with question than i can not help it :P

Comment: Perhaps the OP wants to know how to call a JavaScript function from a link, ex: `<a href="javascript:doWork()">`

Comment: adding `rel="external"` is not the right way to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Just like you would any other JavaScript function (considering jQuery IS JavaScript):

```
var myFunction = function(param1, param2){
    // Do some work
}

myFunction(myValue, myOtherValue);
```

Comment: you can not, once you include the jquery mobile plugin..you can not call it in the same way..because jquery mobile uses ajax to redirect to different pages and an extra # is added in the url

Comment: i think you people have not used jquery mobile plug in as per yet

Comment: @hasan - Your question mentions nothing about a jQuery Mobile plugin. I simply asks how to call a function.

Comment: Sorry guys...Found the answer ..You have add "rel='external'" in every link in your project when using jquery mobile only than the new page will behave like normal page :)...If you think I was stupid with question than i can not help it :P

Answer (score 3):

The same way you call a Javascript function without jQuery mobile.

Comment: you can not, once you include the jquery mobile plugin..you can not call it in the same way..because jquery mobile uses ajax to redirect to different pages and an extra # is added in the url

Comment: i think you people have not used jquery mobile plug in as per yet

Comment: @hasan: What on earth are you talking about? Function calls are function calls, no matter what your URL is.

Comment: @SLaks please use jquery mobile plug in once :)

Comment: @hasan: You are wrong.  No matter what the plugin does, _you can still call functions_.

Comment: Sorry guys...Found the answer ..You have add "rel='external'" in every link in your project when using jquery mobile only than the new page will behave like normal page :)...If you think I was stupid with question than i can not help it :P

Answer (score 3):

This is not an answer to the question, but it adresses the OP needs.

When a page is loaded by jquery mobile, it is fetched with AJAX, so there is no DOMready anymore. Also - the contents of the page's head are not loaded. You have to put your code in a file and link it to all the pages. Then write `pageshow` event handlers.

Pages that jquery mobile loads in are always tagged with a `data-url` atribute. To get something done when the page is being displayed (just like it used to be with DOMready) you can:

```
$("div:jqmData(url='thatone.html')").live('pageshow',function(e){
//stuff
});
```

And this definition can be anywhere in the main page or in external scripts. It requires jQuery to be loaded. Thanks to the live method it doesn't require the page to exist before the event happens, or even at all.